# Pyside QTreeWidget Double-clicking on multiple items

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I've got a qTreeWidget-based interface where I double click on individual items to toggle them on and off. However, I'd like to be able to bulk-toggle them by selecting multiple objects and double clicking them, but when you double click on any item you immediately lose the multi-selection.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Many thanks for your time,

Nick

Comment: It's the default selection behavior, and changing it is quite counter-intuitive. Are you sure your users will figure out what to expect from this action?

Comment: You're quite right, it's a bit of an awkward one. I didn't really want to have to add any extra buttons to the interface, just an extension of what it already does. Perhaps I should look into a right-click menu solution instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selection/deselection of items is controlled by the mouse-press event, which obviously happens before the double-click is registered. So you need to "eat" the mouse-press at the appropriate moment.

This example allows double-clicking when the meta-key is pressed:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.tree = QtGui.QTreeWidget(self)
        for text in 'One Two Three Four'.split():
            parent = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree, [text])
            for text in 'Red Blue Green'.split():
                child = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(parent, [text])
            parent.setExpanded(True)
        self.tree.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
        self.tree.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.tree)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (source is self.tree.viewport() and
            isinstance(event, QtGui.QMouseEvent) and
            event.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.MetaModifier):
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick:
                print('meta-double-click')
                return True
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
                # kill selection when meta-key is also pressed
                return True
        return super(Window, self).eventFilter(source, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(800, 300, 300, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

The first step would be to setup an event that fires whenever an item is double clicked, like so:

```
treeWidget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(onClickItem)
```

where onClickItem is:

```
def onClickItem(item):
    print('Text of first column in item is ', item.text(0))
```

Of course you'll want to do something a bit more fancy inside onClickItem().